# Download and Extract Remote Application File from Website

Tags: powershell, intune, remoteapp

I am pretty new to IT Administration and I think I have a pretty complicated request but I want to know if it is even possible through Intune. I have an application that I want to deploy and I think I would either need to package the application as a Win32 app or via a Powershell Script. I basically would need to download the zip from this website, extract the contents, open the WCX, silently pass through the prompts, and pin the app to the taskbar. Again I am not sure if this is even possible but this would save me a lot of trouble if there was an easy way to do this. Here is the link.

https://kb.tempworks.com/help/how-to-add-an-enterprise-shortcut-to-the-desktop

Answer (score 0):

To download a file, use `Invoke-WebRequest` with the `-OutFile` parameter.

To Install a .wcx you use rundll like this:

```
rundll32.exe 'tsworkspace,WorkspaceSilentSetup' C:\Path\To\The.wcx
```

(There's a whole wrapper script for that on the old technet [script gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/313a95b3-a698-4bb0-9ed6-d89a47eacc72))

It's **impossible** by design to pin things to users' task bar or start menu programmatically (well, you *could* script a bunch of hotkey presses and clicks, but don't).